# Passing parameters to a procedure executed by DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, jobs

I have a scheduler program that runs a stored procedure that requires input parameters.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM
    (program_name          => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_SCHEMA_STARTING');
END;
/
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM
    (
      program_name         => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_SCHEMA_STARTING'
     ,program_type         => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
     ,program_action       => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_STATUS'
     ,number_of_arguments  => 0
     ,enabled              => FALSE
     ,comments             => NULL
    );

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
    (name                  => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_SCHEMA_STARTING');
END;
/
```

How can I pass parameters to the `EXPORT_STATUS` procedure?

I changed it into program that runs a PL/SQL BLOCK so far:

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM
    (
      program_name         => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_SCHEMA_STARTING'
     ,program_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
     ,program_action       => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_STATUS(''STARTING''); END;'
     ,number_of_arguments  => 0
     ,enabled              => FALSE
     ,comments             => NULL
    );

  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE
    (name                  => 'MYSCHEMA.EXPORT_SCHEMA_STARTING');
END;
/
```

It works as I expected. But if anyone knows how to keep it in the previous format, will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to look at [`DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72328) and [`DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72429) procedures.

Answer (score 6):

When you create a program with [`CREATE_PROGRAM` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#i1010013), you can specify how many arguments it expects with `number_of_arguments` parameter.

If, for some reason, you want to modify some attribute (`number_of_arguments` in our case) for an existing Scheduler object (program in our case), you don't need to drop the object and re-create it with new attribute value again, you can just use [`SET_ATTRIBUTE` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHDAIIH) instead:

```
  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(
      name => 'my_program'
    , attribute => 'number_of_arguments'
    , value => 1);
```

Once you've created the program and all of its attributes are set, you can define the arguments of the program (if there are any) with [`DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#i1011161):

```
dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(
    program_name => 'my_program'
  , argument_position => 1
  , argument_type => 'VARCHAR2'
  , default_value => 'STARTING'
);
```

Here, we defined the program argument and its default value. We could have left the default value unspecified, but in this case we would have to set the value of the argument using [`SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72429). For example, if you created the job and specified the associated program as follows:

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name => 'call_my_program'
  , program_name => 'my_program'
  ...
);
```

You would have to set the value of the argument in the program associated with the job this way:

```
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(
    job_name => 'call_my_program'
  , argument_position => 1
  , argument_value => 'STARTING');
```

If you have defined the default value of an argument for a program with `DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT` procedure and also set the value of the argument with `SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` procedure, the argument value set with `SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` procedure will override the default argument value set with `DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT` procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-- create job

DECLARE
    v_jobname       VARCHAR2 (30) := 'myScheduledJob';
    v_date_format   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name =>
            v_jobname,
        job_type =>
            'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action =>
            'XXTEST_JOBS_procedure',
        number_of_arguments =>
            2,
        start_date =>
            TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('2015-06-03 19:05:00 Europe/Berlin',
                             'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS TZR'),
        --start_date => systimestamp + interval '1' minute,
        repeat_interval =>
            NULL,
        --end_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-07-29 05:30:00 Europe/Berlin','YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS TZR'),
        job_class =>
            '"SYS"."DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
        enabled =>
            FALSE,
        auto_drop =>
            FALSE,
        comments =>
            'Do run something longrunning');

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (job_name            => v_jobname,
                                               argument_position   => 1,
                                               argument_value      => 10);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (
        job_name            => v_jobname,
        argument_position   => 2,
        argument_value      => 'Hello World');
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable (name => v_jobname);
    COMMIT;
    
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (job_name => v_jobname);
END;
```

Thanks to [this article by Sven Weller](https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/scheduled-job-on-procedure-with-date-parameters/).

Answer (score 0):

1. create another procedure with passing paramaters in it
2. schedule the above procedure with creare job

> ```
>   CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE XX_COPY_SALES_ORDER
>         IS 
>         RETCD NUMBER;
>         RETBUFF VARCHAR2(100);
>         BEGIN
>          XX_PROCESS_PKG.MAIN   (RETCD,RETBUFF,NULL);
>         END;
> ```

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'XX_COPY_SALES_ORDER',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'XX_COPY_SALES_ORDER',
   start_date         =>  '07-MAY-16 07.00.00 PM US/Central',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '05-OCT-25 07.00.00 PM US/Central',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
  --job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
  enabled             => TRUE,
  comments           =>  'COMMETNS');
END;
```